# How to update table and apply existing filters

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We are using the excellent Tabulator JS library. We poll our server at intervals to refresh the data in our table. We are trying to achieve the following behaviour when this happens.

1. Update the existing data in the table
2. Add any new rows that "Match" the current filters
3. Remove any rows that have changed and don't match the filters
4. Keep the existing scroll position
5. Keep any selected rows.
6. If the filters are removed show the latest data.

There are 3 methods to update Tabulator

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/update

1. SetData (we use this when we first fetch)
2. updateData
3. updateOrAddData (we use this on repeated fetches but row edits don't get filtered out)
4. replaceData

In the documents is mentions that 'replaceData' will update existing table data with out resetting the scroll position or selected rows, this does not seem to be the case. 'updateData' does update the data and leaves the scroll pos and selected rows as is, BUT it does not apply the filters, for example if a row is updated out of the scope of the current filter it still shows?

Our code right now:

```
if (replace) {
   table.updateOrAddData(data); //replaceData
} else {
   table.setData(data);
}
```

We need the table to update and meet our requirements in my above points 1-6. I would expect one of the methods listed (replace, update) would do this and in the docs it seems they should, but in our tests this fails. How can we achieve the desired results?

We are using version 4.5 downgraded from 4.4.

Edit:

So for example if we update the table with data and one of the rows in the table does not exist in the new data, that update does not persist. Unless we use setData which resets the scroll position, undoes all selected rows and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Tabulator, 4.9, adds a [refreshFilter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/filter#manage) function. This should accomplish most of your request.

My own testing also show that the sorters are also refreshed by this function.

`table.refreshFilter();`

Answer (score 0):

You can either call manually [Redraw](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/layout#redraw)

```
table.redraw(true); //trigger full rerender including all data and rows
```

or just use [reactive data](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/reactivity#reactive-data)

```
reactiveData:true, //enable reactive data
data:tableData, //assign data array
```

Comment: Thanks. The redraw does not fix the issue. I have not tried reactive data as this requires an addition module and makes the data-->table live. It seems more efficient to construct our own procedure to run the various processes to update the table in situ and without affecting filters, selected rows or scroll position. I have posted this code in my own answer. I feel this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and looking through Tabulator 4.5 docs it seems that the table can not update existing data, re-apply filters, remove dead rows (those not in the new data from the server) from one of the update, replace methods. From what I can understand this can be achieved by the code I have written below, which uses the updateOrAddData method, the setFilter method and my own async function to loop the table and remove dead rows.

```
    // var data= new data from server - any array.
    // get the existing filters, update the data or add any new rows.
    var f = table.getFilters();
        table.updateOrAddData(data); //replaceData with server copy

        var keys = [],
            r = table.getRows();
        // make a list of all the  keys in our server data, this will make it faster to remove dead rows.
        data.forEach(function(item) { keys.push(item.id); });
        // remove any dead rows in the data that do not belong start at row 0
        removeDeadRows(0, function() {
            table.setFilter(f); //re-apply filters when finished.
        });

    // iterate the table test if each row is in our key list, if not remove it.
        function removeDeadRows(pos, cb) {
            if (!r[pos]) return cb();
            var c = pos + 1;
            try {
                if (keys.indexOf(r[pos].getData().id) > 0) return removeDeadRows(c, cb);
                r[pos].delete();
                removeDeadRows(c, cb);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                cb();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your OP, this is what you were looking for ?

```
var selected,visible;
var t = new Tabulator("#tabulator", {
    data:[
        {id:1,title:'One'},{id:2,title:'Two'},{id:3,title:'Three'},{id:4,title:'Four'},{id:5,title:'Five'},
        {id:11,title:'Eleven'},{id:12,title:'Twelve'},{id:13,title:'Thirteen'},{id:14,title:'Fourteen'},{id:15,title:'Fifteen'},
    ],
    height:"10em",
    selectable:true,
    columns:[ {title:'Title',field:'title',headerFilter:'input'}, ],
    initialHeaderFilter:[{field:'title',value:'e'}],
    dataLoading:function(d) { if (t) { selected = t.getSelectedData().map(o => o['id']); visible = t.getData('visible').map(o => o['id']); } },
    dataLoaded:function(d) { if (t) { t.selectRow(selected); t.scrollToRow(visible); } }
});
t.selectRow([3,11,15]);
t.scrollToRow(15);
setTimeout(() => {
    t.replaceData([
        {id:3,title:'Three'},{id:5,title:'Five'},{id:6,title:'Six'},{id:7,title:'Seven'},{id:8,title:'Eight'},{id:9,title:'Nine'},{id:10,title:'Ten'},
        {id:13,title:'Thirteen'},{id:15,title:'Fifteen'},{id:16,title:'Sixteen'},{id:17,title:'Seventeen'},{id:18,title:'Eighteen'},{id:19,title:'Nineteen'},{id:20,title:'Twenty'},
    ]);
},5000);
```

Comment: Actually, none of the use of the visible variable is required. You're right, replaceData() preserves scrolling place. but it doesn't preserve selectedData()

Comment: Also, at Point 6, you didn't say whether scrollingPos should be maintained when the filter is removed. If so, look at the dataFiltering and dataFiltered callbacks and use the same way.

Comment: Yes correct. Also if you have filters the new rows added will show on the table regardless of whether they match. I find it strange that Tabulator has 2/3 update methods but non seem to carry out the correct task of keeping the table in-sync with server data where new rows appear, old rows are removed, existing rows update. Without simply rebuilding the whole table. In my code/in my answer it manages to carry out that task.

Comment: Regarding the filters. Well that is not the issue. The table may or may not have a filter applied. Regardless when I update the data from the server I would expect the table to hold position, keep filters and keep selected rows. So if the user is part way in an operation, filters, selected rows or scroll are not lost.

Comment: I think the updateOrAddRow is the best match function. It fails to remove dead rows, and adds new rows regardless of what filters are set - Seems to me be a design fault or bug. Either way - In my example i run this as it keeps scroll POS and selected rows. Then I removed the dead rows, and them re-apply the filters. This seems to be the best methods I can find to get the desired result. What do you think?

Comment: no, I dont think your statement about new rows showing up with filters applied is correct. In my example code, the Six doesnt doesnt show after the replaceData() is called

Comment: well we dont know your entire use case to know what a user part way through an operation means. But your question about maintaining scrollpos is not an easy one to solve. If you update the data and ALL of the rows on the current screen are removed, where do you want the scrolling to go ?